# Blower fan has to toggled on/off in order to shut off

Tags: hvac, z-wave

Pardon my lack of terminology or specifics.
I have a heat pump HVAC system for my house. A few years ago I installed a Z-wave GoControl smart thermostat. The thermostat is powered by batteries and not the HVAC system itself. The problem I have had ever since I installed it (and simply dealt with), is the blower fan more times than not, does not shut itself off. The only way it does is if I toggle the fan button on the thermostat between [Auto] *wait for a click inside the thermostat* [On] *wait for click* and eventually when it lands on [Auto] it shuts off. Sometimes I have to toggle back and forth 20-30 times.

Scenarios this occurs

1. Run fan for ## hour(s) via a mobile app. Usually I choose 1 hour.
2. Scenario #1, but after about 10 minutes to flush the ducts of hot air, turn on A/C as well. The fan eventually goes back to [Auto]. Then when the A/C reaches its setpoint a few hours later, I can hear the A/C shut off but the fan continues.

I mentioned it has been a few years of this because I thought it might be a stuck relay or something. But it's clearly never full given and failed.

Thoughts? More info needed?

Comment: Problem started with installing the Z-wave thermostat?  Sounds like setup was not done right, thermostat not compatible with your HVAC, or thermostat has always been  wonky.

Comment: Hard to say. Previous thermostat was one of those really old mercury based brass/brown analogue thermostats. Wasn't really using it when I moved in and replaced it with the zwave almost immediately.

I'm probably naively thinking that if it was installed incorrectly or not compatible, other things would not function properly (or I would have damaged something). Not sure what to think since it's just been intermittent issue for years.

Comment: What make and model is your heatpump?

Comment: Sorry for delay, had to climb up into the attic crawlspace to look and the weather has been pretty hot. 
First Co. 36VDXO-HP (might be 36UDXO-HP)